# How to print values from dictionary in pairs opposite each other

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, this code:

```
data = {"Name": "salat "
, "Ingredient 1": "salad ", "Number of in1": 60
, "Ingredient 2": "salt ", "Number of in2": 19
, "Ingredient 3": "oil ", "Number of in3": 20
, "Ingredient 4": "cheese ", "Number of in4": 50
, "Ingredient 5": "pepper", "Number of in5": 10
}
for key in data:
    print(data[key])
```

prints:

```
salat
salad
60
salt 
19
oil 
20
cheese 
50
pepper
10
```

but I want:

```
salat 
salad 60
salt 19
oil 20
cheese 50
pepper 10
```

How can I get this?

Comment: `for value in data.values(): print(value)`

Comment: I whant that value "salad" and "60", for example, be in tha same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the dictionary is always sorted this way, you could check if the item if even or odd and change the `print` end value:

```
for i,v in enumerate(data.values()):
    print(v, end=' ' if i%2 else '\n')
```

output:

```
salat 
salad  60
salt  19
oil  20
cheese  50
pepper 10
```